# Changing Picturebox Image, C#

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

What i am trying to do is to change my picture boxes' image in the code, i do not know the syntax and have looked around quite a bit for it but cannot find it. Please be explanatory as i am new to C#, Any and all help is appreciated

Thank you for reading.

Comment: It's in your title: `PictureBox.Image`.  Make it equal to the image you want to use.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Don't get too discouraged by all the downvotes, but this is not a good question for this site.  The reason being is that the answer is clearly in the [`PictureBox`'s class documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox(v=vs.110).aspx).   Here's some suggestions on how to use SO:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

```
    // Construct an image object from a file in the local directory.
    // ... This file must exist in the solution.
    Image image = Image.FromFile("myLocalImage.png");
    // Set the PictureBox image property to this image.
    // ... Then, adjust its height and width properties.
    pictureBox1.Image = image;
    pictureBox1.Height = image.Height;
    pictureBox1.Width = image.Width;
```